# I want to create method inside if condition in android

Tags: java, syntax-error

by using onItemClick and if Condition i match the string array with raw folder MP3 File 
By click listview songs i need to play songs on other activity by call just that mplay method. Pls help me....

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{     
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer3;




    if(position==0)
    {
        public void mplay() **<--------- I Get error in this Line**
                    {
        mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gayatri);
        mPlayer2.start();
                    }

    }
```

Comment: It's a syntax error. You can't declare a method in a regular code block. Maybe study the JAVA language tutorial?

Comment: to call a method in the other Activity just: `Play.this.mplay()` and the method must exit on that Activity

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `mplay()` , not to create mpaly() in if condition

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{     
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer3;

    if(position==0)
    {
       mplay();
      //or mplay(R.raw.gayatri);
    }


}

 public void mplay()
                    {
        mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, R.raw.gayatri);
        mPlayer2.start();
                    }



  public void mplay(int id)
                        {
            mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, id);
            mPlayer2.start();
                        }
```

Comment: can i create mplay() in one activity and declare mplay method in another activity

Comment: yes . Create mpalay() in any file , or call then with help of object

Comment: I Need to play nearly 150 by this method any special method for that playing 150 songs from raw folder by clicking listview

Comment: Check edited ans. you can create one function and each time you just have to pass song name

Answer (score 0):

In Java you aren't able to do such thing, but you can return an instance of anonymous class containing only one method inside.

Answer (score 0):

On Item click

```
if(position==0)
{
   mplay();
}
```

In your activity define method mplay()

```
      public void mplay()
       {

        //do something
       }
```

Comment: I Need to play nearly 150 by this method any special method for that playing 150 songs from raw folder by clicking listview